# How to render edit button with click event for dataTable in vuejs

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, vuejs3

I am trying to render dynamic buttons for dataTable rows in **vuejs**. Buttons are displaying for each row, but the problem is, @click event is not working there. My codes are:

```
$('#users').DataTable({
    data: response.data,
    columns: [
         { data: 'id' },
         { data: 'role_id' },
         { data: 'name' },
         { data: 'email' },
         {
            data: null,
            className: "dt-center editor-edit",
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                 return '<input type="button"'+ @click=toggleModal()+'" class="name" id=n-"' + 
                 meta.row + '" value="Name"/>;
            },
            orderable: false
          }
     ]
})
```

Comment: mixing vuejs and jquery isn't easy, as you've discovered

Comment: yes, very bad experience lol

Comment: I'm surprised that the code you've shown doesn't produce errors instead of actually running to be honest `@click=toggleModal()` is an invalid JS statement, yet, that's what your code will try parse, won't run at all, none of that code should run

Comment: this shows error in vscode to be honest, but dataTable fetches data+buttons with no issue lol

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, with just hardcode @click="toggleModal()" with the string.

```
<input type="button" @click="toggleModal()" class="name" id=n-"' + 
             meta.row + '" value="Name"/>
```

Comment: does not work brother

Comment: I'm sorry, can you try again with <input type="button" onclick="toggleModal()" class="name" id=n-"' + 
             meta.row + '" value="Name"/>

Comment: onClick too does not work lol ... dataTable should integrate proper documentations for vuejs

Comment: `dataTable should integrate proper documentations for vuejs` - why? dataTable is jQuery ... if you're using jQuery AND vuejs, you're *doing it wrong™* - i.e. never use jquery and vuejs at the same time ... ever

Comment: I agree, but I am required to integrated dataTable in vuejs ... have no other way

Comment: @Bravo not true, there is `datatables-vue` for this very reason

Comment: @TimHallman - sure, but look at the documentation of how it's used ... nothing like the code in the question